# How do you export a div and its contents into an image in jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

If I have a drawing program with jquery, everything is done inside a #canvas div.  How do I take whats in this div (including all the drawings a user makes) and save that to an image file?  I know its much more complicated, but how should I approach this?

Answer (score 0):

I'd treat everything that is being drawn as an SVG file, so you can use xml.
Then, server side, you could convert it in whichever file format you like.